# CSS transition not being applied on adding a class with JS

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

So I am trying to do something which I'm sure I must have done countless times before but for some reason, just isn't working this time.

I have the following bit of html:

```
<span class="toggle-nav"><span>Toggle navigation</span></span>
```

and the following css:

```
.toggle-nav {
  position absolute
  top:1rem;
  left:1rem;
  z-index 10
  width: 4rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: $primary;
  span
  span:before
  span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height:.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out, transform .5s ease-in-out
  }

  span {
    top: .5rem;
    width: 3rem;
    margin-left .5rem
  }

  .open & {
    span {
      background-color: transparent;
      &:after {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        top: 1rem;
      }
      &:before {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a bit of JS which will toggle a class of 'open' to the parent of toggle-nav. All of the desired styles are being applied and it looks exactly how I want it to. However, for some reason the transition part is being completely ignored. It's been a long day and I'm sure I'm just missing something stupidly simple but I can't see it. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Here is a codepen so you can see more clearly what is happening:

http://codepen.io/alexward1981/pen/PZVBZV

Frustratingly, the codepen works but my site doesn't so I guess something else is interfering with it.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Btw, `margin-left .5rem` here're `:` and `;` skipped.

Comment: It's written in Stylus so the missing commas and semicolons are fine :) I'm making a codepen as we speak.

Comment: Codepen added to question :)

Comment: Maybe post a link to the webpage then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with reflow, another function is moving it to it's parent element on click to prevent another class from applying a blur to it. I've restructured the code so it doesn't need to do that anymore. Problem solved.

BTW for anyone who comes here and thinks "well how do I fix a reflow?" It's simple.

Instead of:

```
el.addClass('open');
```

Just do:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        el.addClass('open');
    }, 0
);
```

The same goes for the removeClass part.